# Ember.js routing

Tags: routes, ember.js

I am struggling to find any good Ember.js routing examples.

Should I use an addon like [this](https://github.com/ud3323/ember-routing) or I personally like the look of [this](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager)?

I see there is a routes collection as part of the State object but I cannot find any examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Due to significant changes in the Ember.js router, this answer is obsolete *since around the 1.0 PRE-RELEASE*. MOdern versions of ember.js should [use the standard routing guidelines](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/)**

I guess this is (at leas for now) very personal.
I like ghempton's ember-routemanager. If you need some help with it I could help you.
Together with his ember-layout package as well, they work nice together.

http://codebrief.com/2012/02/anatomy-of-a-complex-ember-js-app-part-i-states-and-routes/

Comment: I've gone with ember-routemanager and the layoutmanager.  I like the way they play together.

I will supply patches if anything breaks.

Comment: As far as I could tell this technique no longer works with ember.js 0.9.8.1 which includes native routing, See pangrantz' answer below for the * * * official * * * solution ;)

Comment: Yes, definitely, this is the correct approach right now, by the time I wrote this answer it was not available.

Answer (score 21):

Routing has been recently made available in core Ember.js, see Tom Dale's [blog post](http://tomdale.net/2012/05/ember-routing/).

Core developer Yehuda Katz wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2728699) about the usage of the new routing feature. It's a good read, and besides routing also states how it can be integrated with controllers.

To get the basic idea, here's a code example taken from the gist:

```js
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.State.extend({
    index: Ember.State.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'calendar.index'
    }),

    calendar: Ember.State.extend({
      route: '/calendar',

      index: Ember.State.extend({
        route: '/'
      }),

      preferences: Ember.State.extend({
        route: '/preferences'
      })
    }),

    mail: Ember.State.extend({
      route: '/mail',

      index: Ember.State.extend({
        route: '/'
      }),

      preferences: Ember.State.extend({
        route: '/preferences'
      })
    })
  })
});

// If the user navigates to the page with the URL
// www.myapp.com/, you will start in the root.calendar.index state.
// The redirection to the calendar.index state will cause the URL
// to be updated to www.myapp.com/calendar

router.transitionTo('preferences');

// URL => www.myapp.com/calendar/preferences

router.transitionTo('mail.preferences');

// URL => www.myapp.com/mail/preferences

router.transitionTo('index');

// URL => www.myapp.com/mail
```

Answer (score 3):

I use [sproutcore-routing](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing) in my apps because:

- it plays nice with ember.js
- it is [actively maintained](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing/commits/master/)
- it is used by some bigger ember.js apps (e.g. have a look at [travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci) [routing code](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app.js))

For documentation have a look at the [spoutcore-routing tests](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing/blob/master/tests/routing.js)

Comment: I am not so sure, the SC namespace was done away with in Ember 0.9.6.

This means they no longer play well together and is part of the general move away from Sproutcore.  IMO I must stress.

I could just alias the namespace but I am wonder if one of the newer projects would not be better.

I was originally going to use sproutcore-routing until the 0.9.6

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend this guide on the ember site: http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/

I believe this content is very new-- I certainly didn't notice it a couple of weeks ago when I first started trying to understand Ember routing.

Answer (score 3):

Ember routing changed entirely over Christmas. They posted some new documentation to help, but removed all the old tutorials. I'm guessing the old ways of doing things (in the previous answers) will be deprecated.
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/